# creating a representation of an object when no string to work with (python, django)

Tags: python, django, string

i'm using the django tutorial (which i've done earlier) to create a simple timesheet app and struggling to understand the **str** method. works fine for the Project class because i have string name, but the Worktime model only has a date and integer so it won't accept a **str** method. all the docs I've read on **str** don't seem to provide an answer to this question, how can I create a useful representation of this object when i don't have a string to work with? the logged_today method doesn't work either but that's another question.. thanks!

```
class Project (models.Model):
  project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  hourly_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.project_name

class Worktime (models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  date_logged = models.DateField('date logged')
  time_worked = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.time_worked
  def logged_today(self):
    return self.date_logged == timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

The string representation can be anything you like. It doesn't even have to be a field on the model, although obviously that would make it pretty useless.

But of course you *can* use the date and/or the integer, as long as you convert them to a string first. So one good representation might be:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Worked %s hours on %s' % (self.time_worked, self.date_loggged)
```

or anything else that makes sense for your use case.